# Array equal two different values and change a variable dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, equals

I want a user to key in an ID Number. When the user clicks on a button, the code will look for an array that has a list of all the id numbers to check if it exists. It will then go to check the price of that id number. Based on the price and what ID number was looked up I want this to change a variable called 'cost' dynamically. So for example, a user keys in the number "5555" The code looks up if the ID 5555 exists, if it does, it checks the price of that id. Based on that price, I want it to change a variable called cost. Likewise, if I looked up an id of "1234". It would look up the id, if it existed, got the price and then changed the variable called cost.

I don't even know where to begin with this. I was thinking about using arrays to map the id numbers and price but I don't know if that will work. I want a number to equal another number essentially and then change a variable based on the second number and I can't think of how to do that.

```
id[0] = new Array(2)
id[1] = "5555";
id[2] = "6789";
price = new Array(2)
price[0] = 45;
price[1] = 18;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an object as a dictionary like object.

```
// Default val for cost
var cost = -1;

// Create your dictionary (key/value pairs)
// "key": value (e.g. The key "5555" maps to the value '45')
var list = {
    "5555": 45,
    "6789": 18
};

// jQuery click event wiring (not relevant to the question)
$("#yourButton").click(function() {
    // Get the value of the input field with the id 'yourInput' (this is done with jQuery)
    var input = $("#yourInput").val();

    // If the list has a key that matches what the user typed,
    // set `cost` to its value, otherwise, set it to negative one.
    // This is shorthand syntax. See below for its equivalent
    cost = list[input] || -1;

    // Above is equivalent to
    /*
    if (list[input])
        cost = list[input];
    else
        cost = -1;
    */

    // Log the value of cost to the console
    console.log(cost);
});
```

Comment: Could you explain this more? I don't understand how that works.

Comment: @Brian I added comments. Let me know if that doesn't cut it.